# Does Quickbooks Online API support to void an invoice?

Tags: quickbooks-online

To void an invoice on the webapp, there is a VOID link in the bottom, or through a hack way by entering "Voided" to the field statement memo.

The way to void an invoice is not documented on the api doc. What is the proper way to do so on API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There isn't one.</strike>

This isn't supported.

Intuit has just added support for this in their last QuickBooks Online update.

Details can be found here:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Invoice

```
REQUEST URL
Sandbox Base URL: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Production Base URL: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com

POST /v3/company/<companyID>/invoice?operation=void
Content type: application/json

{
  "Id": "129",
  "SyncToken": "0"
}
```

Comment: Looking forward to the next version then. Seems like v2 supports it with batch operation.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to give up on this when I found the following in the [PHP SDK section](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0210_ipp_php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_synchronous_calls)

### Void() Method

```
$dataService->Void($customerObj);
```

That's literally all it says with no other details. I'll try to remember to update this answer after I test it.

Comment: Confirmed. Use $voidResponse = $dataService->Void($invoiceEntity); where $invoiceEntity and $voidResponse are instances of QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPInvoice

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `TxnVoid` call.

You supply the type like this:

```
typedef enum {tvtARRefundCreditCard, tvtBill, tvtBillPaymentCheck, tvtBillPaymentCreditCard, tvtCharge, tvtCheck, tvtCreditCardCharge, tvtCreditCardCredit, tvtCreditMemo, tvtDeposit, tvtInventoryAdjustment, tvtInvoice, tvtItemReceipt, tvtJournalEntry, tvtSalesReceipt, tvtVendorCredit} ENTxnVoidType
```

and then the `TxnID` that you wish to void

Comment: This is incorrect, as the poster is asking about QuickBooks Online, and this answer is for QuickBooks for Windows.